# How to control keyboard backlight using hotkeys

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, keyboard-backlight

How can I turn increase and decrease the keyboard backlight in notebook on Linux using the same hotkeys used on Windows?

In Windows I can control the keyboard backlight by pressing hotkeys (<kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>F9</kbd> to decrease and <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd> to increase), but in Linux it doesn't seems to have these hotkeys implemented as the keyboard backlight is a new and not most spread feature for the notebooks/ultrabooks.

Note: The <kbd>Fn</kbd> is working for normal features like display brightness and sound, just for controlling the keyboard backlight it is not configured correctly... But it works in the Linux, as I can turn it on in the Grub2 boot device selector, but not in the running Linux OS.

Just some extra-specs: OS : Linux (Mint Cinnamon 17). Notebook: Samsung Ativ Book 6.

Comment: UEFI or MBR booting? If the former, you may not be loading the `samsung-laptop` module which controls this functionality.

Comment: I think it is MBR, because in the bios I need to put uefi/efi mixed setup instead of just uefi that is default. But just to be sure, there is any command that can I run to return the booting system mode?

Comment: UEFI booted systems will have `/sys/firmware/efi` present.

Answer (score 7):

The keys usually used to control keyboard backlight are `XF86KbdBrightnessUp` and `XF86KbdBrightnessDown`. You just need to find a way to bind it to the following shell command lines (and set the sudoers as needed):

```
# Light off the leds
sudo echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness
# Light on the leds (full power)
sudo echo 100 > /sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `yad` to control backlight brightness; I used the following slider for chromebook Acer cb714 running fatdog linux

```
yad --no-buttons --on-top --vertical --scale --print-partial --value=$(cat /sys/class/leds/*::kbd_backlight/brightness) | while read line; do echo "$line" > /sys/class/leds/*::kbd_backlight/brightness; sleep 0.01; done &
```

Answer (score 1):

Following https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/keyboard_backlight I ended up using D-Bus to avoid requiring root privileges:

```
$ dbus-send --system --type=method_call --print-reply=literal \
  --dest="org.freedesktop.UPower" "/org/freedesktop/UPower/KbdBacklight" \
  "org.freedesktop.UPower.KbdBacklight.GetMaxBrightness"

   int32 2

$ dbus-send --system --type=method_call \
  --dest="org.freedesktop.UPower" "/org/freedesktop/UPower/KbdBacklight" \
  "org.freedesktop.UPower.KbdBacklight.SetBrightness" int32:1
```

I imagine that to incrementally adjust the brightness you could write some small shell script or other tool that does a `GetBrightness` call followed by `SetBrightness` with a change applied to the previous value. Haven't tried that since I don't have any dedicated brightness adjustment buttons on my keyboard and don't want to clobber any existing key bindings. At least for now.